# What is the Degrees of Freedom of linear combination of parameters from a OLS regression estimated on imputed data

Tags: r, regression, prediction, missing-data, multiple-imputation

I've estimated an OLS regression on imputed data with results combined using Rubin's Rules.

I'd like to get the confidence interval for a linear combination of coefficients. However, because I'm using Rubin's Rules, each of the coefficients has its own degrees of freedom (df). I'm not sure what the correct df should be for linear combinations. For instance below, what is the correct df for `1*bmi + 2*age`? Does anyone have any ideas please?

Example:

```
library(mice)
imp <- mice(nhanes, m=3, print = FALSE) %>% mice::complete("long")
result <- imp %>% 
  by(factor(.$.imp),
     function(x) lm(formula = chl ~ age + bmi,data=x)) %>%
  MIcombine()
glht(result,"1*bmi + 2*age = 0")
```

Note `glht` does not give the correct confidence intervals (it understimates), which can be seen by comparing `MIcombine` with `glht`.

```
glht(result,"bmi = 0")
summary(result)
```

Thanks.